# Adding new repositories to obsolete distribution?

Tags: repository

I don't even know if what I'm asking is doable, but suppose I loved one EOL version of Ubuntu and wanted not to upgrade to a supported version but rather add/replace the old repositories with the most current one. Will my EOL system break down as soon as I start updating and/or upgrading?

To illustrate, take ubuntu 10.04. Will adding new 16.04 repos kill it?

Comment: Your EOL system will break eventually.

Comment: Is this question fake? Because the best EOL Ubuntu is "utopic unicorn" xD

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the standard available repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the current ones then your question makes no sense because this will upgrade the system anyway since it installs the latest version of software available in the repositories. This method is officially unsupported but it does work. I always use this method. There's one catch if you do this you'll have to do it on a regular basis. Going from 10.04 to 16.04 means skipping 6 years or 12 versions and that's a very long period. You might encounter incompatibilities or even break the system.